# Implementing input validation on console applications

Tags: vb.net

I'm relatively new to VB. This is the only bit I can't manage to code on my project. Most of the online resources are either for c# or anything but console applications. This is what I've gotten to.

```
  Dim choiceNum As String

    Console.WriteLine("1] Accuracy Option")
    Console.WriteLine("2] Quadratic Equation")
    Console.WriteLine("3] Monte-Carlo Integration")
    Console.WriteLine("4] Prime Decision")
    Console.WriteLine("5] Exit")
    Console.WriteLine()

    Console.Write("Please enter the number that corresponds to your choice (from 1 - 5)" + vbNewLine)
    choiceNum = Console.ReadLine()


    If (IsNumeric(choiceNum) = True) Then
        choiceNum = Convert.ToInt32(choiceNum)


        If (choiceNum = "1") Then
            accOp()
        ElseIf (choiceNum = "2") Then
            quadEq()
        ElseIf (choiceNum = "3") Then
            monte()
        ElseIf (choiceNum = "4") Then
            prime()
        ElseIf (choiceNum = "5") Then
            Application.Exit()
        Else
            Do
                Console.WriteLine("Enter valid input")
                choiceNum = Console.ReadLine()


                If (choiceNum = "1") Then
                    accOp()
                ElseIf (choiceNum = "2") Then
                    quadEq()
                ElseIf (choiceNum = "3") Then
                    monte()
                ElseIf (choiceNum = "4") Then
                    prime()
                ElseIf (choiceNum = "5") Then
                    Application.Exit()
                End If

            Loop
        End If
    Else
        Do
            Console.WriteLine("Enter valid input")
            choiceNum = Console.ReadLine()


            If (choiceNum = "1") Then
                accOp()
            ElseIf (choiceNum = "2") Then
                quadEq()
            ElseIf (choiceNum = "3") Then
                monte()
            ElseIf (choiceNum = "4") Then
                prime()
            ElseIf (choiceNum = "5") Then
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        Loop
    End If
```

This way of validating is really inefficient and tends to crash if there are special characters. 'numChoice' was originally defined as an integer but that crashed my program if I entered text, so I changed it to a string type and converted the input to an integer later on. Can someone tell me if there is a more efficient way to do this? I've tried using While loops too but the results were even worse.

Below is my next attempt at validation, except, the loop only exits when I enter "1" or "2".

```
Dim valid As Boolean = False

    Console.Write("Enter value of a" + vbNewLine)
    a = Console.ReadLine().Trim()
    Do While Not valid
        valid = False
        Select Case a
            Case "-2147483648" To "2147483647"
                valid = True
            Case Else
                Console.WriteLine("Enter valid input for a")
                a = Console.ReadLine().Trim()
                valid = False
        End Select


    Loop
```

Comment: Research `Integer.TryParse()` for the "trends to crash" part.  Its not really something limited to console apps - users enter whacky stuff all the time, everywhere

Comment: Please turn `Option Strict On` and `Option Explicit On` for your VB code - it'll make your code far better automagically (once you remove the new compilation errors).

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways you can do it, here's one way:

```
    Dim valid As Boolean = False
    Dim choiceNum As String

    Console.WriteLine("1] Accuracy Option")
    Console.WriteLine("2] Quadratic Equation")
    Console.WriteLine("3] Monte-Carlo Integration")
    Console.WriteLine("4] Prime Decision")
    Console.WriteLine("5] Exit")
    Console.WriteLine()

    Console.Write("Please enter the number that corresponds to your choice (from 1 - 5)" + vbNewLine)

    Do While Not valid

        choiceNum = Console.ReadLine().Trim()

        Select Case choiceNum 
            Case "1"
               valid = True
               accOp()
            Case "2"
               valid = True
               quadEq()
            Case "3"
               valid = True
               monte()
            Case "4"
               valid = True
               prime()
            Case "5"
               valid = True
               Application.Exit()
            Case Else
               valid = False
               Console.WriteLine("Enter valid input")
        End Select
    Loop
```

You can also change the `Do/Loop` to make it a bit cleaner by setting the valid flag to true at the start:

```
    Do While Not valid

        valid = True

        choiceNum = Console.ReadLine().Trim()

        Select Case choiceNum 
            Case "1"
               accOp()
            Case "2"
               quadEq()
            Case "3"
               monte()
            Case "4"
               prime()
            Case "5"
               Application.Exit()
            Case Else
               valid = False
               Console.WriteLine("Enter valid input")
        End Select
    Loop
```

Check if a string contains only numbers:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim A As String = "100"
Dim num As New Regex("^\d+$")
Select Case num.IsMatch(a)
    Case True
        MsgBox("Yes")
    Case Else
        MsgBox("false")
End Select
```

Technically, if you really wanted to, you could check for an integer range in a select case, though I'm not sure that's the best way to accomplish what you want:

```
Case -2147483648 To 2147483647
```

Using TryParse:

```
Dim valid As Boolean = False

Console.Write("Enter value of a" + vbNewLine)
a = Console.ReadLine().Trim()
Do While Not valid
    valid = False
    Select Case Int32.TryParse(a, Nothing)
        Case True
            valid = True
        Case Else
            Console.WriteLine("Enter valid input for a")
            a = Console.ReadLine().Trim()
            valid = False
    End Select


Loop
```

Comment: I found this incredibly useful. Would you happen to know if there is a reserved word for all integers? For example, 
`Select case A || Case "all integers" || Case Else`

Comment: Not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for but you can use regular expressions to check for a number, I updated the code above.

Comment: I tried using `Case "-2147483648" To "2147483647"` (quotation marks since I had to enter them as strings) since it's a reasonably large range, but it only exits the loop if I enter 1 or 2 for some reason, otherwise it keeps asking me to enter valid input. I've edited in the code where I'm trying to implement this.

Comment: If you enclose them in quotes, it's taken as a string, not an integer. I wouldn't recommend that method anyway. I've added additional code above showing how to use `TryParse` with your example. If it's successful converting the input, then you know it's an integer.